# change from auto detected to autocomplete wunderground

Tags: jquery, api, autocomplete, wunderground

this is my code blow wunderground weather , and he all ready working fine , but i want to make change , this change well be from auto detected to autocomplete api , and i make try but get error , i just some one edit my code change to autocomplete api .

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(weather) {

 $.ajax({
 url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/eb7a37c339cfd624/geolookup/conditions/forecast10day/lang:AR/q/autoip.json",
 dataType : "jsonp",
 timeout: 8000,
    error: function(jqXHR) { 
        if(jqXHR.status==0) {
            alert(" ÙŠØ±Ø¬Ù‰ ØªØ­Ù‚ÙŠÙ‚ Ù…Ù† Ø§ØªØµØ§Ù„Ùƒ Ø¨Ø§Ù„Ø§Ù†ØªØ±Ù†Øª ")
        }
    },
success : function(data) {

var degree = data.current_observation.wind_degrees;
var direction = check(degree);
///information //
var html = ' <div class="ui-grid-solo"> <div class="ui-block-a">';

html +=  '<h1 class="text-center">'+ data.current_observation.temp_c + '</h1>'
html +=  '<h4 class="text-center">'+ data.current_observation.display_location.city + '</h4>'
html +=  '<h4 class="text-center">'+ data.current_observation.observation_time + '</h4>'
html += '</div></div>';

  $("#temp").append(html).hide().fadeIn("slow");


///forecast now //


var html = '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a">';

html +=  ''+ direction + ''

html+= '<h3 class="text-center"> Ø¨Ø³Ø±Ø¹Ø© '+data.current_observation.wind_kph + ' Ø¹Ù‚Ø¯Ø© </h3></div>'

html+= ' <div class="ui-block-b"><h3 class="text-center">Ø§Ù„Ø§Ø¬ÙˆØ§Ø¡ '+ data.current_observation.weather +'</h3><table style="width: 100%"><tr style="text-align: -moz-center;"><td style="width: 1%"><span style="width: 10%; text-align: center;text-align: center; font-size: 25px;"class="text-center">'+ data.current_observation.feelslike_c +'</span></td><td style="width: 19%"><span  style="font-size:20px;">Ø´Ø¹ÙˆØ± Ø¨Ù‡Ø§</span><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconsmind/outline/32/T-Shirt-icon.png" style="float: right; width: 25px;" /></td></tr></table><table style="width: 100%"><tr><td style="float: right;font-size:large;direction:rtl"> Ø§Ù„Ø±Ø·ÙˆØ¨Ø© '+ data.current_observation.relative_humidity +'</td><td style="width: 50px"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/24/Science-Humidity-icon.png" /style="float: right;"></td></tr></table>  <table style="width: 100%"><tr><td style="font-size: 18px;"> Ø¶ØºØ· Ø¬ÙˆÙŠ '+ data.current_observation.pressure_mb +'</td><td style="width: 25px"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/24/Science-Pressure-icon.png" /style="float: right;"></td></tr></table>'

html += '</div></div>';

  $("#news").append(html).hide().fadeIn("slow");

  //wind//

var html = '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a">';

html +=  ''+ direction + ''

html+= '<h3 class="text-center"> Ø¨Ø³Ø±Ø¹Ø© '+data.current_observation.wind_kph + ' Ø¹Ù‚Ø¯Ø© </h3></div>'

html+= ' <div class="ui-block-b"><h3 class="text-center"> Ø¨Ø³Ø±Ø¹Ø© '+data.current_observation.wind_kph + ' Ø¹Ù‚Ø¯Ø© </h3>'

html += '</div></div>';

  $("#wind").append(html).hide().fadeIn("slow");








  ///10days///

var dayArray = data.forecast.txt_forecast['forecastday'];

var html = '<div>';
for(var i=0; i<dayArray.length; i+=2)

html += '<h3>'+data.forecast.txt_forecast.forecastday[i]['title']+ " : " +data.forecast.txt_forecast.forecastday[i]['fcttext_metric']+'</h3></div>'

html += '</div>';

  $("#10").append(html).hide().fadeIn("slow");


 }
 });
 });
```